# I can ot compile a GUID number generation code

Tags: c, wix, guid

I need to use a GUID number for a Wix project installer but I am in trouble with my C code. I try to compile a short program with gcc 4.5 in C but I have an error that I can not resolve. I use a template for project that run everytime but not here.
Here is the debugger message:

```
 obj\Debug\guid.o||In function `main':|
D:\_wrk\guid.c|21|undefined reference to `CoCreateGuid@4'|
D:\_wrk\guid.c|22|undefined reference to `StringFromCLSID@8'|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

and here is my short code:

```
#define _OLEAUT32_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unknwn.h>
#include <objbase.h>
#include <rpc.h>


GUID guid;
WORD* wstrGUID[100];
char strGUID[100];
int count, i;

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf (stderr, "SYNTAX: UUIDGEN <number-of-GUIDs-to-generate>\n");
    return 1;
    }
  count = atoi (argv[1]);
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    CoCreateGuid (&guid);
    StringFromCLSID (&guid, wstrGUID);
    WideCharToMultiByte (CP_ACP, 0, *wstrGUID, -1, strGUID, MAX_PATH, NULL, NULL);
    printf ("%s\n", strGUID);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Can somebody help me ? thanks . Christophe

Comment: They're OS API calls.  Include Windows.h?

Comment: What is this `#include <unknwn.h>` ?

Comment: @all: Yes, I have resolved the problem. I forgot to add ole32.dll in linker option section. Thanks to all.  `<Add library="ole32" />`

Comment: @Michi : unknwn.h contain some declarations for use the objects with the MIDL "ressources compiler" on Windows (.res and GUID for example)

Comment: @Martin James: Yes windows.h is called with unknwn.h

Comment: @Michi : i saw your questions. In time you re searching a coloring method for console. This is non ansi and for Windows (perhaps the same on Linux) che 's pretty. [link]http://codes-sources.commentcamarche.net/source/101227-compilateur-reverse-ti-basic-ti82-83-stat